# Calling Snowflake stored procedures from a Talend job - error handling

Tags: stored-procedures, error-handling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I have a Talend job that calls several Snowflake stored procedures in sequence. It uses tDBRow components connected by OnComponentOk to call the SPs. It works fine, except when an SP throws an error the OnComponentOk trigger still kicks off the next component - even though I see the error message in the Talend job log. What can I do to make sure the job terminates if any of the stored procedures fail?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: you have to not tick the die on error in tDBRow  and  if you are using talend with license just simply delete the OnComponentOk  link and use  tparallelize component without ticking the die on error  fonctionnality in the component